# Как правильно настроить fossil, для того чтобы fossil clone скачивал с сервера репозиторий?

Tags: контроль-версий

Создал новый проект в fossil, в отдельной папке, находящейся в home. Запустил и настроил встроенный в него веб-сервер. При выполнении

```
fossil clone http://адрес-сервера:8080/ <имя проекта>
```

получаю ошибку:

```
    Bytes      Cards  Artifacts     Deltas
Sent:              53          1          0          0
server says: 404 Not Found
Total network traffic: 201 bytes sent, 0 bytes received
server returned an error - clone aborted
```

Если же выполнить команду, указывая путь из home до проекта

```
fossil clone http://адрес-сервера:8080/ <путь до проекта>/<имя проекта>
```

То получаю следующую ошибку:

```
SQLITE_CANTOPEN: cannot open file at line 31811 of [b0888047bb]
unable to open database file

If you have recently updated your fossil executable, you might
need to run "fossil all rebuild" to bring the repository
schemas up to date.
```

Получается, никак не склонировать себе проект.

Answer (score 1):

повторил Ваш эксперимент. Все хорошо клонируется и работает. Делал так:
в одном терминале

```
$ mkdir ftest
$ cd ftest/
$ fossil ui test
Fossil internal error: repository does not exist or is in an unreadable directory: test
$ fossil init test
project-id: eac2b870974a88ac6282253d5e7e1426f6c53263
server-id:  85c6e8fc53422b66535af7c0be5975f69a60d325
admin-user: vadim (initial password is "4fd3bc")
$ fossil ui test
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

В втором терминале

```
$ mkdir test2
$ cd test2
$ fossil clone "http://127.0.0.1:8080/test" test2
Round-trips: 2   Artifacts sent: 0  received: 3
Clone finished with 477 bytes sent, 1157 bytes received
Rebuilding repository meta-data...
  100.0% complete...
project-id: eac2b870974a88ac6282253d5e7e1426f6c53263
admin-user: vadim (password is "9b8e98")
```

Единственное отличие - у меня есть кавычки вокруг урла.

В браузере открывается страница?